# DolphinDB: How to perform matrix-like multiplication on tables?

Tags: datatable, dolphindb, inner-product

I create two tables, *tb1* and *tb2*, with the following script:

```
tb1=table(`sym1`sym2`sym3`sym4`sym5 as SYMBOL,NULL NULL 1 NULL NULL as block1,NULL 1 NULL NULL NULL as block2,1 NULL NULL 1 NULL as block3,NULL 1 NULL NULL 1 as block4)
tb2=table(`sym1`sym2`sym3`sym4`sym5 as SYMBOL,1+double(seq(1,5))/10 as col1,2+double(seq(1,5))/10 as col2,3+double(seq(1,5))/10 as col3)
```

I want to calculate the inner product between the non-null cell values of each “block” column in *tb1* and the values in the corresponding cell in *tb2*, and return the result in the format of *tb3*, as shown in the figure below. How to achieve this in DolphinDB?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert *tb1* and *tb2* into matrices *m1* and *m2* and use the `cross` function to apply the `wsum` function to the permutation of all individual elements of *m1* and *m2*. If the column names of the two matrices differ, use the `align` function to align the two matrices first. Refer to the following script and output:

```
tb1=table(`sym1`sym2`sym3`sym4`sym5 as SYMBOL,NULL NULL 1 NULL NULL as block1,NULL 1 NULL NULL NULL as block2,1 NULL NULL 1 NULL as block3,NULL 1 NULL NULL 1 as block4)
tb2=table(`sym1`sym3`sym4 as SYMBOL,1+double(seq(1,3))/10 as col1,2+double(seq(1,3))/10 as col2,3+double(seq(1,3))/10 as col3)

m1 = matrix(tb1[,1:]).rename!(tb1.SYMBOL, tb1.colNames()[1:])
m2 = matrix(tb2[,1:]).rename!(tb2.SYMBOL, tb2.colNames()[1:])
mm1, mm2 = align(m1, m2, 'fj', true)
re = cross(wsum, mm1, mm2)
```

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| block1 | 1.2 | 2.2 | 3.2 |
| block2 |  |  |  |
| block3 | 2.4 | 4.4 | 6.4 |
| block4 |  |  |  |